# How to Add Navigation Controller to AppDelegate for Universal App in IOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

How to Add Navigation Controller for Universal App ie.. iPhone and iPad in AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder? Are you using Storyboards? Which OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 7):

Simple as this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you even need to do that much work. Just name the XIBs with `~ipad` and `~iphone` and it gets done automatically. Something like `ViewController~ipad.xib`.

Comment: @nevanking, We don't know the .xib file names, therefore I don't want confuse him by adding that part to the answer.. it is not the problem he is trying to solve,